# Return all possible combinations of a string when splitted into n strings

Tags: python, string, list, chunks

I made a search for stackoverflow about this but couldn't find a way to do it. It probably involves itertools.

I want to find all the possible results of splitting a string, say the string `thisisateststring` into `n` (equal or unequal length, doesn't matter, both should be included) strings.

For example let `n` be `3`:

```
[["thisisat", "eststrin", "g"], ["th", "isisates", "tstring"], ............]
```

Comment: Are empty substrings allowed?

Comment: So mathematically, you are looking for all the different possible sums of size `n` for length(string), and then permuting them?

Comment: @C.B.: From his question I understand that he only wants all possible ways of splitting a string into n substrings (so when you concatenage s1 + s2 + s3 you get back the original string).

Comment: SvenMarnach, yes they are allowed.
C.B., yes you can say it that way, but Paul's sounds more concise, but its probably the same with what you're saying.
Paul, correct exactly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Including empty strings in your results will be rather awkward with `itertools.combinations()`.  It's probably easiest to write your own recursive version:

```
def partitions(s, k):
    if not k:
        yield [s]
        return
    for i in range(len(s) + 1):
        for tail in partitions(s[i:], k - 1):
            yield [s[:i]] + tail
```

This will work for any number `k` of desired partitions for any string `s`.

Comment: I know it's a silly (and very easy) question but is there a way for it to return a list, because when I execute the code it returns:
    <generator object partitions at 0x1026230a0>

Comment: Call it like `list(partitions("abcde", 3))`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `itertools.combinations` here. You simply need to pick two splitting points to generate each resulting string:

```
from itertools import combinations
s = "thisisateststring"
pools = range(1, len(s))
res = [[s[:p], s[p:q], s[q:]] for p, q in combinations(pools, 2)]
print res[0]
print res[-1]
```

Output:

```
['t', 'h', 'isisateststring']
['thisisateststri', 'n', 'g']
```

Comment: This does not include empty strings, an it is awkward to extent to empty strings.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recipe for partitioning a sequence into n groups, based on [code by Raymond Hettinger](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576795/):

```
import itertools as IT

def partition_into_n(iterable, n, chain=IT.chain, map=map):
    """
    Based on http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576795/ (Raymond Hettinger)
    Modified to include empty partitions, and restricted to partitions of length n
    """
    s = iterable if hasattr(iterable, '__getslice__') else tuple(iterable)
    m = len(s)
    first, middle, last = [0], range(m + 1), [m]
    getslice = s.__getslice__
    return (map(getslice, chain(first, div), chain(div, last))
            for div in IT.combinations_with_replacement(middle, n - 1))
```

---

```
In [149]: list(partition_into_n(s, 3))
Out[149]: 
[['', '', 'thisisateststring'],
 ['', 't', 'hisisateststring'],
 ['', 'th', 'isisateststring'],
 ['', 'thi', 'sisateststring'],
 ...
 ['thisisateststrin', '', 'g'],
 ['thisisateststrin', 'g', ''],
 ['thisisateststring', '', '']]
```

---

It's slower than the recursive solution for small `n`,

```
def partitions_recursive(s, n):
    if not n>1:
        yield [s]
        return
    for i in range(len(s) + 1):
        for tail in partitions_recursive(s[i:], n - 1):
            yield [s[:i]] + tail

s = "thisisateststring"
In [150]: %timeit list(partition_into_n(s, 3))
1000 loops, best of 3: 354 µs per loop

In [151]: %timeit list(partitions_recursive(s, 3))
10000 loops, best of 3: 180 µs per loop
```

but as you might expect, it is faster for large `n` (as the recursion depth increases):

```
In [152]: %timeit list(partition_into_n(s, 10))
1 loops, best of 3: 9.2 s per loop

In [153]: %timeit list(partitions_recursive(s, 10))
1 loops, best of 3: 10.2 s per loop
```